# API Permissions - Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-app-registration

I'm using Microsoft Graph API to create an application making an HTTP request using the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Example:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
Content-type: application/json

```
{
  "displayName": "MyAppName",
  "signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs"
}
```

But I need to add some API permissions (Microsoft Graph Application permissions) when creating the applications so I can do other operations like getting the Azure AD groups, modify them, create users, etc. Is there a way to add and grant the permissions programmatically as well without doing it through the portal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Microsoft Graph object ID

The first thing you'll need is the object ID of Microsoft Graph service principal in your tenant.

`00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is the globally unique application ID for Microsoft Graph, which we can use to get the object ID by making a request like below.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appid eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'&$select=id,appid,appDisplayName
```

**Example response**

The object ID we need is the `id` in the response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#servicePrincipals(id,appId,appDisplayName)",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "bd0a624d-11f8-44ab-a015-d8f276d75ad3",
            "appId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "appDisplayName": "Microsoft Graph"
        }
    ]
}
```

**References**

[Application IDs for commonly used Microsoft applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/verify-first-party-apps-sign-in#application-ids-for-commonly-used-microsoft-applications)

## Adding API Permissions

You can add the API permissions, which is separate from granting admin consent.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{application_id}
```

**Headers**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Authorization | Bearer {access token} |
| Content-Type | application/json |

**Body**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| resourceAppId | The API resource to add permissions from, in this case `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is for Microsoft Graph |
| resourceAccess | Array of permissions containing the ID and type |
| id | Use the globally unique ID of the permission want to add, which you can reference from [All permissions and IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#all-permissions-and-ids) |
| type | For delegated permissions, use `Scope`. For application permissions, use `Role` |

**Example body**

The below permissions are for `User.Read` (delegated), `openid` (delegated), and `Directory.Read.All` (application)

```
{
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7ab1d382-f21e-4acd-a863-ba3e13f7da61",
                    "type": "Role"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**References**

[Update application API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[requiredResourceAccess resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/requiredresourceaccess?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[resourceAccess resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/resourceaccess?view=graph-rest-1.0)

## Granting admin consent

Important to note that you can only grant admin consent with the API for `delegated` permissions. For `application` permissions, you'll need to use the Portal and click the button.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants
```

**Headers**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Authorization | Bearer {access token} |

**Body**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| clientId | The Enterprise Application object ID for which you want to grant consent to |
| consentType | Indicates if authorization is granted for the client application to impersonate all users or only a specific user. AllPrincipals indicates authorization to impersonate all users. Principal indicates authorization to impersonate a specific user. Consent on behalf of all users can be granted by an administrator. Non-admin users may be authorized to consent on behalf of themselves in some cases, for some delegated permissions. Required. Supports $filter (eq only). |
| resourceId | Use the object ID we obtained earlier for the Microsoft Graph service principal |
| scope | A space-separated list of the claim values for delegated permissions which you want to grant admin consent to |

**Example body**

```
{
    "clientId": "7f244605-717f-408f-96fb-d369678cea56",
    "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
    "resourceId": "bd0a624d-11f8-44ab-a015-d8f276d75ad3",
    "scope": "openid User.Read"
}
```

**References**

[Create oAuth2PermissionGrant API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[oAuth2PermissionGrant resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you’re creating more then 10 applications, I would just go through the portal.

1. Creating secrets through the api is not very easy.
2. The portal has wizards and explanations for most options

Granting permissions and creating applications can be done at the same time, you can also create the application and then have an admin do the admin consent.

Admin consent explained: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin

Comment: The problem is that the project I'm working on will be used by other companies and each one needs its own application, so indeed I'll be creating several of them and I won't have access to their directories, that's the reason everything needs to be done programmatically.

Comment: Are you running the application in your azure cloud or is the client running the application? In the first case you only need a single application and just ask the client to do admin consent.